# Show $\sum_k \frac{1}{4^k|x-b_k|}$ converges in many points.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider the following problem from Axler's "Measure, integration and real analysis" (p72):

[image]

Honestly, I'm not even sure where to begin. This problem appears in the section that proves Lusin's and Egorov's theorem. The abstract Lebesgue integral is not yet introduced so I can not use that. Otherwise I could just show that the sum has finite integral and could conclude.

I think we can write $f= \lim_k f_k$ as a pointwise limit of the partial sums but this probably does not quite help.

Further attempt:

I tried to show $$\{x: f(x) < 1\}$$
contains a set of infinite measure but was unsuccesful.
A hint to get started is appreciated!

Comment: If $(c_k)$ is a positive sequence with $\sum c_k < +\infty$, then the series certainly converges at $x$ if $\frac{1}{4^k\lvert x-b_k\rvert} \leqslant c_k$ for all $k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I can see that this helps when $x$ is not in the closure of $\{b_1, b_2, \dots \}$ because then the denominator can be estimated. But what if this sequence is dense?

Comment: Play around with it a bit. It doesn't matter whether $\{b_k : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense or not.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you give a further hint? I cannot proceed.

Comment: This problem comes from a book published in Springer's Graduate Texts in Mathematics series. This book is also in Springer's Open Access program. Thus the electronic version of the book is legally free to the world. It can be downloaded at http://measure.axler.net/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a sequence $(c_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of (strictly) positive real numbers such that $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} c_k$ converges. For the exercise it may be useful to pick the sequence such that $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} c_k < 1$. We shall assume that this is the case, but let me point out that dropping that assumption yields further interesting results about $f$.

Then it is clear that $f(x) < 1$ at least for all $x$ such that
$$\frac{1}{4^k \lvert x - b_k\rvert} \leqslant c_k$$
holds for all $k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$. Taking complements we obtain
$$\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \geqslant 1 \} \subseteq \bigcup_{k = 1}^{\infty} \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : c_k4^k\lvert x-b_k\rvert < 1\}\,.$$
Now a small rewrite shows that a suitable choice of $c_k$ proves that $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \geqslant 1\}$ has finite measure, namely the measure is bounded by
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{4^kc_k}\,.$$

---

> Otherwise I could just show that the sum has finite integral and could conclude.

That doesn't work, the sum has infinite integral. We have
$$\int_{b_1 + \varepsilon}^{b_1 + 1} f(x)\,dx \geqslant \int_{b_1 + \varepsilon}^{b_1+1} \frac{dx}{4(x-b_1)} = \frac{1}{4}\log \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$$
for all $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$. Letting $\varepsilon \to 0$ we see that the integral is infinite.

Comment: How do you get $|\{x \in \Bbb{R}: c_k 4^k |x-b_k| < 1 \}| \leq \frac{2}{4^k c_k}$?

Comment: It is the interval $\Bigl(b_k - \frac{1}{4^kc_k}, b_k + \frac{1}{4^kc_k}\Bigr)$.

Comment: Thanks! Everything is very clear!

Comment: I guess it is too hot outside to think properly :P